# How does one prevent a JList from selecting elements when dragging beyond the end of its list?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlist, mouselistener

A very similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138665/how-to-prevent-jlist-from-making-selection-outside-cell-bounds), and while I acknowledge it, the question's solution doesn't quite solve my question. A `JList`, when clicked on, will select the index list item closest to the mouse click. A `JList` will also do this for every click+drag event fire.

**I would like to prevent my `JList` from selecting items during click+drag events when the click+drag location is outside the visible list. How would I go about this?**

I had considered overriding a different method, one involved in the click+drag events of selecting list items. I thought to try the `setSelectionInterval()` method.

```
JList<String list = new JList<String>(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public int locationToIndex(Point location) {
            int index = super.locationToIndex(location);
            if (index != -1 && !getCellBounds(index, index).contains(location)) {
                clearSelection();
                return -1;
                //an excellent click-only solution to prohibit the selecting of 
                //items from beyond the visible list
            }
            else {
                return index;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void setSelectionInterval(int anchor, int lead) {
            super.setSelectionInterval(anchor, lead);
            System.out.println("setSelectionInterval");
        }           
    };
```

I found that each time I click+drag anywhere on the displayed `JList`, I get the System.out message of "setSelectionInterval" that I added to the method above. I don't know where to go from here in terms of overriding methods. Maybe that is not how I should approach this. In the source code for `setSelectionInterval()` I got lost trying to find my way through to a whatever listener is involved, so I came here. :p

I'd greatly appreciate any pointers to where I should be looking or a solution altogether. Thanks in advance!

This is an SSCCE example that is close to how I am set up. As it is, the list will not select an item when a click-only event is fired away from the list items themselves. I would like this same effect to happen when click+drag events are fired away from the list items.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        String[] data = {"Luke", "Jeff", "Bryce"};
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(data){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public int locationToIndex(Point location) {
                System.out.println("location to index");
                int index = super.locationToIndex(location);
                if (index != -1 && !getCellBounds(index, index).contains(location)) {
                    clearSelection();
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return index;
                }
            }
        }

        content.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't know how I would, sorry. I can't get what I'm trying to work.

Comment: *"I can't get what I'm trying to work"*  An SSCCE does not have to 'work', but it must comply with the terms of the abbreviation. Read the article, if there is anything in it you do not understand, ask.  I am well placed to explain.

Comment: I threw one in to simulate the environment I would like this question answered in. I hope it is sufficient. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If disabling the whole dragging feature is acceptable, then the following should help:

```
@Override
protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED != e.getID()) {
        super.processMouseMotionEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to prevent my JList from selecting items during click+drag events when the click+drag location is outside the visible list.

Not sure I understand the requirement. Lets start with the first row being selected.

If you click on the first row and then continue to drag to the second the 2nd row gets highlighted. Continue dragging and the 3rd row gets highlighted. Continue dragging past the 3rd row and what do you want to happen?

Are you saying that you want the first row to be selected because that is where you started? If this is what you are asking, then you would need to look at the BasicListUI. This is where the mouse listeners are added to the JList. You would somehow need to handle the mousePressed event to save the currently selected row. You would then somehow need to override the default behaviour of the mouseDragged code to reset the selected row when you start to drag outside the last row.

I have no idea how to do all this.

> I get the System.out message of "setSelectionInterval" that I added to the method above

Trying to override the code in that method is too late. The selection will continue to be updated as you drag the mouse. You don't know if this method is being called because the mouse is really on the last row or past the last row because you don't have access to the mouse point.

I suppose you could try to use the MouseInfo class to determine where the mouse is when this method is invoked, but then somehow you will still need to know that dragging originally started when the first row was selected. I have no idea how to do this either.

Comment: Starting the mouse at the first row, which selects the first list item, then dragging it down to the second row, which selects the second list item, and the same for the third. I like all of that functionality, but when the mouse is dragged below the third list item I would like it to not select anything. I'd like it to only select items the mouse actually hovers over.

I am fairly confident I could handle the coding for it, but I can't figure out where I should be looking to modify/add code.

Comment: I think it could be agreed upon that I'm looking to add/modify code that deals with mouse events. Reading your post again, I think I will try the BasicListUI mouse listeners being added and start there. Even if I arrive at a dead end, thanks for giving me an idea of where to start.